# iOS Swift 3 present MFMailComposeViewController leads to crash

Tags: ios, iphone

Hey I am using this code to send an email from within my app

```
@IBAction func sendEmail(_ sender: Any) {
        let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

        // Configure the fields of the interface.
        composeVC.setToRecipients(["test@gmail.com"])
        composeVC.setSubject("Feedback")
        composeVC.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)

        // Present the view controller modally.
        self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil) //CRASHES
    }

    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                               didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        // Check the result or perform other tasks.

        // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

The app is live and emails from users do reach me. Often they are empty except for "Sent from my iPhone" but I don't think that's a programming issue. What is an issue tho is that apparently, last week, **8 devices dropped a crash report because of the "//CRASHES" line.**

I think the simulator crashes when trying to do this but I haven't used the simulator for this installation for weeks so those crashreports on iTunesConnect are legit crashes.

What happens if the user doesn't have the email app installed?

[image]

Comment: Your device does not have mail application installed it seems. Or you have not properly configured mail account.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify that the user has setup the device for sending mail by calling

```
[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]
```

before performing any actions

Comment: Thanks, I will implement this in the next update and tick your answer if it helps or no one else replies. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple Documentation [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)

> Before presenting the mail compose view controller, always call the the `canSendMail()` method to see if the current device is configured to send email. If the user’s device is not set up for the delivery of email, you can notify the user or simply disable the email dispatch features in your application. You should not attempt to use this interface if the canSendMail() method returns false.

So, initialization of mail compose view controller using `MFMailComposeViewController()` returns nil, if the user’s device is not set up for the delivery of email and app is terminating due to present a nil modal view controller.

Therefore, before presenting the mail compose view controller you should alway check device's mail settings.

So try this lines of code

```
@IBAction func sendEmail(_ sender: Any) {
    if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        print("Mail services are not available")
        return
    }

    let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    // Configure the fields of the interface.
    composeVC.setToRecipients(["test@gmail.com"])
    composeVC.setSubject("Feedback")
    composeVC.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)

    // Present the view controller modally.
    self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil) //CRASHES
}
```